# Range<String.Index> Versus String.Index

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I am having an issue understanding the difference between Range-String.Index- and String.Index

For example:

```
func returnHtmlContent() -> String {
    let filePath = URL(string:"xxx.htm")
    filePath?.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource();
    let htmlFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "getData", ofType: "htm");
    let html = try! String(contentsOfFile: htmlFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8);
    filePath?.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource();
    return html;
};
func refactorHtml(content: String) -> String {
    let StartingString = "<div id=\"1\">";
    let EndingString   = "</div></form>";

    func selectString() -> String {
        var htmlContent = returnHtmlContent();
        let charLocationStart = htmlContent.range(of: StartingString);
        let charLocationEnd   = htmlContent.range(of: EndingString);

        htmlContent.remove(at: charLocationStart);
        return htmlContent;
    };
    let formattedBody = selectString();
    return formattedBody;
};
refactorHtml(content: returnHtmlContent());
```

The idea in pseudocode

```
Generated HTMLBody
Pass To Function that formats
Remove all characters before StartingString
Remove all Characters After EndingString
Send NewString to Variable
```

Now - when I try to find the index position I cant seem to get the right value type, this is the error I am getting

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Range<String.Index>?' to expected argument type 'String.Index'
```

This is running in a playground

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for [`Range`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/range)?

Comment: @Alexander, I have trouble finding what I need on the apple documentation site. If I may how does this relate to the question, a range is a sequence of values like 1...100 - What is a range of String.Index though is that a 1...(Index.Pos Where string occurs)?

Comment: String indices aren't integers. They're opaque objects (of type `String.Index`) which can be used to subscript into a String to obtain a character. Ranges aren't limited to only `Range<Int>`. If you look at the declaration of `Range`, you can see it's generic over any `Bound`, so long as the `Bound` is `Comparable` (which `String.Index` is). So a `Range<String.Index>` is just that. It's a range of string indices, and just like any other range, it has a `lowerBound`, and an `upperBound`.

Comment: @Alexander, Thank you for your explanation! I appreciate it, I think its against site rules to extend my question so I will have to make a new thread.

Comment: No problem. Reply to me here (mention me with @Alexander) and link me the new question, when you post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String indices aren't integers. They're opaque objects (of type `String.Index`) which can be used to subscript into a String to obtain a character.

Ranges aren't limited to only `Range<Int>`. If you look at the declaration of `Range`, you can see it's generic over any `Bound`, so long as the `Bound` is `Comparable` (which `String.Index` is).

So a `Range<String.Index>` is just that. It's a range of string indices, and just like any other range, it has a `lowerBound`, and an `upperBound`.